# Is jQuery cache disabling trick needed if a server returns cache prevention headers?

Tags: jquery, http, http-headers, browser-cache, http-caching

I need to fully prevent caching of Ajax calls results. Jquery ajax() function has a`cache: false` option for this. The option appends timestamp to each requested resource (`?_=1353592676117`). This should do the job, but is not very elegant. It pollutes logs and can be puzzling for someone not familiar with the trick.

Is enabling this option ever needed if the server returns a correct set of cache prevention headers (`no-cache`, `no-store`, `must-revalidate`, optionally also `max-age=0`)? If so, in which cases headers are not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `cache: false` flag if you are setting correct cache prevention response headers at your server.

Answer (score 0):

For a reference: I've discovered one case when cache disabling headers are ignored. In Chrome, if you hit a back button to return to a page that executes a JavaScript, the script is re-executed, but responses to Ajax calls that the script makes are returned from cache, even if they were originally returned with cache disabling headers.